# Prevent tsc from generating declaration file for js component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm maintaining an old react library and I want the new components I'm developing to be typed (so I can get autocompletion and type checking when I use it). but I don't want to rework my old js components (for now at least - not enough time to make it happen).

When I'm compiling the library, declaration file are generated for tsx files (that's good) but also for jsx files. The issue here is that the declaration file for jsx is innacurate. What does typescript do is defining a type with all the props of my jsx component and specifying them as required - even for props which should not be required. So, at use, it trigger warning everywhere when consuming the library.

For example, this component is specified as "having a required classes prop" after compilation:

JSX:

```
const SecondaryButton = ({ children, classes, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <BaseButton
      className={`btn btn-secondary${classes ? ` ${classes}` : ''}`}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </BaseButton>
  );
};
```

d.ts declaration file:

```
export default SecondaryButton;
declare function SecondaryButton({ children, classes, ...props }: {
    [x: string]: any;
    children: any;
    classes: any;
}): JSX.Element;
declare namespace SecondaryButton {
    namespace defaultProps {
        const classes: string;
    }
    namespace propTypes {
        const classes_1: PropTypes.Requireable<string>;
        export { classes_1 as classes };
    }
}
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
```

I though on solution could be not to generate declaration file for my old jsx components, but I don't know how to configure such a behaviour. What do you think about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these files could be excluded in the [tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig)?
See: [include](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) and [exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude).

Or you could disable all javascript files. See: [allowJs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs)

*Note that you could use multiple `tsconfig` files if you wish to keep these files included in certain situations.*

I believe an alternative could be to add a default value to each optional prop in your JSX code, but I haven't tested this.